# Median of two sorted arrays : Termination condition failing

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, median

Below code I have written by following the logic from [Median of two sorted arrays (method - 2)](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/#comment-2158564108)

You can even see the code at [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/FfzexO)

```
class MedianOfTwoArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Note: These are sorted arrays and are of equal length.
        int[] array1 = {1, 12, 15, 26, 38};
        int[] array2 = {2, 13, 17, 30, 45};

        int median = getMedianOfTwoArrays(array1, array2);
        System.out.println(median);
    }

    static int getMedianOfTwoArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        int index1 = array1.length/2;
        int index2 = array2.length/2;

        int m1 = array1[index1];
        int m2 = array2[index2];

        if(m1 == m2) {
            return m1;
        } else {
            return findMedian(array1, array2, 0, array1.length - 1, 0, array2.length - 1);
        }
    }


    static int findMedian(int[] array1, 
                            int[] array2, 
                                int low1, 
                                    int high1, 
                                        int low2, 
                                            int high2) {


        if((high1 - low1 + 1) == 2 && (high2 - low2 + 1) == 2) {
                return (Math.max(array1[low1], array2[low2]) + Math.min(array1[high1], array2[high2]))/2;
        }

        int mid1 = (low1 + high1)/2;
        int mid2 = (low2 + high2)/2;

        int m1 = array1[mid1];
        int m2 = array2[mid2];

        int low1_t = 0;
        int high1_t = 0;
        int low2_t = 0;
        int high2_t = 0;

        if(m1 == m2) {
            return m1;
        } else if(m1 > m2) {
            low1_t = low1;
            high1_t = mid1;
            low2_t = mid2;
            high2_t = high2;
            return findMedian(array1, array2, low1_t, high1_t, low2_t, high2_t);
        } else {
            low1_t = mid1;
            high1_t = high1;
            low2_t = low2;
            high2_t = mid2;
            return findMedian(array1, array2, low1_t, high1_t, low2_t, high2_t);
        }
    }
}
```

It does not work for input arrays like,

```
int[] array1 = {1, 5, 17, 20}; // median is 10
int[] array2 = {4, 8, 13, 19};

int[] array1 = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}; // median is 6
int[] array2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};
```

The problem as per my analysis is, the termination condition. Some how the logic suggessted from geeksforgeeks seems to be having some issue with the termination condition.

```
(Math.max(array1[low1], array2[low2]) + Math.min(array1[high1], array2[high2]))/2;
```

But I could not able to solve it and make it work for the above inputs.
Can someone please look into this issue and let me know where am I making mistake?

Comment: am I right in saying you don't want to merge and sort the arrays (for optimisation reasons)? Otherwise it would make your life easier

Comment: @cahen Yeah. Merging and sorting will be easy as you said. I have written that code too. But this is a different approach of solving the problem for better time complexity. Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main error is that when you do plain `int mid1 = (low1 + high1)/2;` your `mid1` is always shifted to the left, and then you assign `mid1` without taking this shift into account, therefore each nested comparison compares elements of arrays that are shifted left from the intended position, and since median of an array of length `2n` is always `a[n-1]+a[n]/2`, you are comparing wrong elements of arrays after the first performed comparison. You seemingly incorrently implemented this block of Method 2's code:

```
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return getMedian(ar1 + n/2 - 1, ar2, n - n/2 +1);
    else
        return getMedian(ar1 + n/2, ar2, n - n/2);
```

In fact, the simple `assert (high2-low2==high1-low1)` at the entrance to `findMedian()` would alert you of incorrect logic, since with arrays of size 4 the second entrance yields unequal array sizes. The exit condition is pretty fine, as it's directly copied from Method 2's code. Therefore, you need to change the block of assigning `low1_t` and others to the following:

```
    assert (high2-low2==high1-low1); // sanity check
    int n=high1-low1+1; // "n" from logic

    int m1 = median(array1,low1,high1);
    int m2 = median(array2,low2,high2);

    int low1_t = low1;
    int high1_t = high1;
    int low2_t = low2;
    int high2_t = high2;

    if(m1 == m2) {
        return m1;
    } else if(m1 > m2) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            high1_t = high1-n/2+1;
            low2_t = low2+n/2-1;
        } else {
            high1_t = high1-n/2;
            low2_t = low2+n/2;
        }
    } else {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            low1_t = low1+n/2-1;
            high2_t = high2-n/2+1;
        } else {
            low1_t = low1+n/2;
            high2_t = high2-n/2;
        }
    }
    return findMedian(array1, array2, low1_t, high1_t, low2_t, high2_t);
```

And add function `median` like this:

```
static int median(int[] arr, int low,int hig) 
{
    if ((low+hig)%2 == 0) return arr[(low+hig)/2];
    int mid=(low+hig)/2;
    return (arr[mid]+ arr[mid-1])/2;
}
```

Complete example (alter arrays as necessary): http://ideone.com/zY30Vg

Comment: You could assign `low1` to `low1_t`, etc. when declaring them to avoid all these assignations ;)

Comment: @Holt Indeed, those zeroes are not used. I just needed the code to work, cleanup should be done only afterwards.

Comment: +1 .. When I was going through the geeksforgeeks code, even I thought the same that I have not implemented properly while working with even/odd length cases. Will check that and let you know if I am facing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code and it should solve your problem :-

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    int[] ar1 = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
    int[] ar2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};
  System.out.println((int) findMedianSortedArrays(ar1,ar2));
 }

 public static double findMedianSortedArrays(int A[], int B[]) {
  int m = A.length;
  int n = B.length;

  if ((m + n) % 2 != 0) // odd
   return (double) findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1);
  else { // even
   return (findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1) 
    + findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2 - 1, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1)) * 0.5;
  }
 }

 public static int findKth(int A[], int B[], int k, 
  int aStart, int aEnd, int bStart, int bEnd) {

  int aLen = aEnd - aStart + 1;
  int bLen = bEnd - bStart + 1;

  // Handle special cases
  if (aLen == 0)
   return B[bStart + k];
  if (bLen == 0)
   return A[aStart + k];
  if (k == 0)
   return A[aStart] < B[bStart] ? A[aStart] : B[bStart];

  int aMid = aLen * k / (aLen + bLen); // a's middle count
  int bMid = k - aMid - 1; // b's middle count

  // make aMid and bMid to be array index
  aMid = aMid + aStart;
  bMid = bMid + bStart;

  if (A[aMid] > B[bMid]) {
   k = k - (bMid - bStart + 1);
   aEnd = aMid;
   bStart = bMid + 1;
  } else {
   k = k - (aMid - aStart + 1);
   bEnd = bMid;
   aStart = aMid + 1;
  }

  return findKth(A, B, k, aStart, aEnd, bStart, bEnd);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I was looking for the issues in my code rather than a new code. If my code was not fixed then I will look into your solution.